# How can I get ctest to handle WORKING_DIRECTORY with a space?

Tags: cmake

Am on Windows and have the following working directory:

`C:\code\project - windows\build`

I then configured a test within the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_test(NAME MyTest
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\tests.cmd"
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
)
```

I cannot get this test to work when the working directory has a space in it.  If I change the location the code is checked out to i.e:

`C:\code\project_windows\build`

It works without issue.  How can I get CTest to handle a `WORKING_DIRECTORY` with a space in it's path on Windows?

The error I get with `WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"` is:

```
1. 'C:/code/project' is not a recognized as an internal or external command'
```

I then thought it was a simple case of escaping i.e `WORKING_DIRECTORY "\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\""`, but this then fails as well.  It complains about not being able to change into the now escaped working directory i.e `"C:\code\project_windows\build"`

FWIW I think the error is coming down to this part of the codebase:

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/kwsys/SystemTools.cxx#L3373

Comment: The error message `is not a recognized as an internal or external command` smells to be about the **COMMAND** you run, not about WORKING_DIRECTORY. Have you tried to remove WORKING_DIRECTORY parameter and check the message which will be printed by the test in that case?